# Can't add multiple motes in simulation script in Cooja

Tags: javascript, iot, contiki

I am working on a modification to RPL algorithm in Contiki. I am using Cooja for simulations.
I am trying to assess efficiency of my algorithm by adding nodes to the network randomly by a certain distribution (like Gamma distribution). To do this I have to write a script. The problem is, I can't add more than one mote using this script. Here is what I have so far:

```
var motes_array = new Array(); 
moteType = mote.getType();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    motes_array[i] = moteType.generateMote(mote.getSimulation());
    mote.getSimulation().addMote(motes_array[i]);
} 
log.testOK();
```

The above code adds only one mote, although the loop is executed 5 times as expected.

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: That's a tricky one, can't find immediate problem with the code. Why do you need to use `YIELD` anyway? Why not simply execute the loop body 5 times?

Comment: I was hoping that maybe the `YIELD` would somehow help if the motes were added concurrently. However it doesn't change the output. Gonna change the code in question. I think the issue is with Cooja, though I might be wrong.